# Telegram BOT webook sending empty POST

Tags: django, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm trying to get the payload of the webhook in a BOT in Django.

```
@csrf_exempt
def webhook(request):
    print(request.get_full_path())
    print(request.POST)
    print(request.GET)
    return HttpResponse("OK")
```

The webhook calls are working fine

```
{"ok":true,"result":{"url":"...","has_custom_certificate":false,"pending_update_count":0,"last_error_date":1516490058,"last_error_message":"Wrong response from the webhook: 503 Service Unavailable","max_connections":40}}
```

(last_error_message was solved)

```
<QueryDict: {}>
<QueryDict: {}>
[20/Jan/2018 23:16:17] "POST /webhook/secure/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2
```

But above text is what I'm getting in the POST and GET method  each time I get a message. Always empty. Maybe I'm missing something in the Telegram part, since I've made a POST request to the same URL and it's printing correct information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to POST testing data to your own server in order to know if there have something wrong.

[Here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webhooks#testing-your-bot-with-updates) are some payloads you can execute by curl, or [this Android application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=taipei.sean.telegram.botplayground) have webhook debugger for new developers.

Comment: thanks, the curl worked just fine, the solution is print(request.method, request.body)